# str is not callable while importing sys namespace / IronPython

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I am trying to execute Python code from C# and the Python code is having some imports like import sys.

When I am executing without import works fine. But when I include import sys, I'm getting an error saying str is not callable.

Can any one please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

C# code:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        ObjectOperations ops = engine.CreateOperations();
        dynamic[] obj = null;
        //var compilerOptions = (PythonCompilerOptions)engine.GetCompilerOptions();
        try
        {
            ICollection<string> searchPaths = ops.Engine.GetSearchPaths();

            //string dir = @"..\..\Lib";
            //searchPaths.Add(dir);
            //ops.Engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
            //ops.Engine.ImportModule("os");
            //var scope = Python.ImportModule(engine, @"Lib\math");

            var pyScope = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Nidec\PythonScript\CCompute.py", scope);
            var variables = pyScope.GetVariableNames();
            var type1 = variables.ToList()[5];
            var type = variables.ToList().Where(x => !x.Contains("_")).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            var clsName = scope.GetVariable(type);
            var clsObje = ops.CreateInstance(type1);
           
            obj = new dynamic[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                obj[i] = i + 1;
            }

            object pythonClass = engine.Operations.Invoke(scope.GetVariable(type));
            var results = engine.Operations.InvokeMember(pythonClass, "TorqueCalc", null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ironPythonRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();

        }
```

Python code:

```
import sys // when i remove import sys works fine but when I add it back getting error says "str is not callable", while creating instance (ops.CreateInstance(type1))

class AddTest:   
   def TorqueCalc(self, Power, RPM):
      return (Power*1000)/(2  *3.14 * RPM/30)
class MultiTest:   
   def TorqueCalc(self, Power, RPM):
      return Power* RPM
 class MinusTest:   
   def TorqueCalc(self, Power, RPM):
      return Power-RPM
```

Comment: Where do you get that error, exactly?  Is it on the `engine.ExecuteFile`?

Comment: And if you're going to invoke `TorqueCalc`, you have to run it on an object of class `AddTest`. I'm not sure you're doing that.  Aren't you passing the class itself?

Comment: I need to find all method/function names and class names in a python script from IronPthon, how can I find?

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved. The problem is with creating instance ops.CreateInstance(type1). It is expecting object as a parameter but I was passing class name as a string.

var clsName = scope.GetVariable(**type1**);
var clsObje = ops.CreateInstance(clsName);